# UICollectionView not loading on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a `UICollectionView` and its not loading on the screen. In my app delegate I even made it the entry screen and it does not appear just a black screen.

```
class ChatRoom: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    // Struct of Objects
    struct Object {
        var image: UIImage!
        var title: String!
    }

    // Properties
    var object: Object?
    var objects: [Object] = []
    var picker: UIImagePickerController!
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!
    // Instance of a class
    var secondClass : ChatCell?

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Firebase Data
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        // CollectionView
        collectionView2?.delegate = self
        collectionView2?.dataSource = self
        collectionView2?.reloadData()

        // User Logged In
        checkIfUserLoggedIn()

        picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker?.allowsEditing = false
        picker?.delegate = self
        picker?.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
        let object = objects[indexPath.row]

        cell.chatLabel.text = object.title ?? ""
        cell.chatImage.image = object.image ?? UIImage()
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count  
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemWidth = collectionView2.bounds.width
        let itemHeight = collectionView2.bounds.height
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        switch info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        case let .some(image):
            object?.image = image
        default:
            break
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.showCellTitleAlert()
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        object = nil

        dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.collectionView2!.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Alerts
    func showCellTitleAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Cell Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { $0.placeholder = "Enter only 10 characters" }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            self.object = nil
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { _ in
            self.object?.title = (alert.textFields?.first.flatMap { $0.text })!
            self.object.flatMap { self.objects.append($0) }
            self.collectionView2?.reloadData()
        })

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Create new Cell
    @IBAction func didSelectCreateButton() {    
        object = Object()

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Where did you fill objects array ?

Comment: You not yet have item to load.

Comment: Is a root view controller?

Comment: Reload your collectionView At the end of the showCellTitleAlert() just after you present that alert (Just Try) and try checking weather the data after inserting from alert and picker is passed in your object class or not ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I do reload my collectionView at the end of showCellTitleAlert() ... under addAction : "Save"

Answer (score 0):

Here the `collectionView` appears blank because you are not filling the `objects` array which is the `dataSource` for the `collectionView2`.

Comment: Hey how can I fix this? Appreciate the help

Comment: You need to add elements to object array and then reload the collectionView

Comment: I do add elements to the array... I also do reload the collectionView in my viewDidLoad()...

Comment: I'm sorry but Can you specify the function where you are adding elements to objects array ??